# Where can a new, hobbyist, developer go to get feedback?

Tags: java, feedback

I have written a small game in Java, I think it's quite clever, but I don't have any friends who know anything about programing, nor do I have any idea how to get more people to see it.

As a hobby developer I don't have someone watching me to tell me if I am doing well, no boss who I have to impress, or an instructor handing out grades. So I find myself wondering: am I on the right track?

I imagine that there exists a place online, a community site, or a Q&A style site like stack, which deals with this very issue. Someplace where people that know a thing or two are more than happy to take a look at what you're working on, and tell you how it is.

Seems like something any newbie programer would need, so they can stop bad practices early, or learn new ways of doing things in the context of their own code. But not just the code, the whole application, be it a game or a word processor. The code, the UI, the icons, and other graphics, everything is important, but I can't find a place that will do that kind of thing.

The Code Review stack exchange is nice:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

But as one can infer from the name, this site is about code, so the other very important parts of the program would not be within the scope of that site.

I (and I can't be the only one) am looking for someone(s) to take a look at the project as a whole, and its parts, and give me an evaluation. Basically something akin to a grade I would receive were this for a class, but it isn't. As well as some helpful pointers/suggestions.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com -- This is meant to be exactly what you want. You post _working_ code and ask for feedback.

Comment: I specifically talked about that in my question. Will add detail. The issues is that it isn't intended (as far as I can tell) for an entire project. From reading information on the site it appears to be intended for more specific things then "take a look at my multi file, hundreds of lines of code, my graphics, and play the game a bit. Then tell me what you think".

Comment: @zeel You could be a genius and have horrendously-impossible-to-comprehend code. In fact, I'd say being a genius makes it slightly more likely. <requisite_kernighan_quote/>

Comment: I have rewrote the question to better explain the need.

Comment: Your edits improve the question a lot, but IMHO it's still off-topic. Stack Overflow is for actual practical programming problems, not for recommendations for other sites.

Comment: This is a practical programing problem. A compiler telling me it runs, and my own tests can't tell me how well I am actually doing. Any hobbyist programer may face a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) is what you want.

From the [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site):

> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:
>
> 1. Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> 2. Did I write that code?
> 3. Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> 4. To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> 5. Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?
>
> If you answered yes to all the above questions, your question is on-topic for Code Review.

Comment: It also says: "if you can imagine a book written about it" then no. . . plus I want feedback on more than just the code, but the entirety of the applications function.

Comment: For application function, any end-user can tell you if an application is "fun" or not. Besides, fun is completely, 100% subjective. But for code, design patterns, best practices, etc., code review is the right place. You need to have written code that's runnable. Being able to "write a book on it" is to discourage overly broad questions. Your question is highly specific: "I have working code, so can someone look at it and tell me if I can improve it?" That is _exactly_ what the code review site is for, don't be afraid to post your code there.

Comment: I can give it a shot, it just seems slightly out of scope. I think I will ask about it on Meta first, just to be sure.

Comment: Sounds like a plan :) Just make sure you're asking on the code review meta, of course. I'm sure I don't need to remind you about that, but some people...

Comment: Yes, on CR meta: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/607/what-if-we-have-an-entire-small-application-we-want-reviewed

Comment: I am fairly certain that CR is not the appropriate place for this kind of thing. I have reworded my question to better explain the intention, and to address the problems I am facing.

Answer (score 1):

For questions and feedback, a forum would probably be your best bet.  Something like [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net) might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/ is a good place if it's open source and it's a useful application.

Comment: It amazes me that anyone still uses SourceForge now that Github is around.

Comment: Not really what I need. SourceForge and Github are not designed for someone to solicit help, but rather as a place for someone who already has help to coordinate it. Correct me if I'm wrong, could be missing something.